# $ replace to " jQuery" - why this issue "$ is not a function"

Tags: jquery, joomla

what are the differents between  $ and jQuery ?

Now i am working on joomla project , how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: 1) none 2) probably you have `noConflict()` on http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: What are you doing on your Joomla project? Creating a custom template or extension or just hacking the core?

Comment: Joomla usually uses Mootools, why not use it instead of JQuery? It's not really sensible to use both of them.

Comment: @ElijahMadden: Maybe the poster is a seasoned jQueryite, but has never touched Mootools. Maybe the poster knows both, but considers jQuery to be superior. Maybe the poster has third-party jQuery code for which they cannot find a Mootools equivalent. I wouldn't assume they're trying to use jQuery 'just for the hell of it', or to be awkward, or to make their life more difficult than it needs to be :-)

Answer (score 8):

If you only have jQuery installed and no other libraries, then `$` and `jQuery` are the same thing (`$` is an alias for `jQuery`).  If there are multiple libraries installed, each trying to use the `$` symbol, then only one library can have it and it may no longer be used by jQuery.  In that case, you can use the `jQuery` symbol to access all jQuery functions.

jQuery's function [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) will unassign the `$` symbol so it can be used by another library if there is a conflict.  If you are finding that `$` is not defined, then it may be because some code has either already redefined it to be something other than `jQuery` or some code has explicitly unassigned it with `jQuery.noConflict()`.

If that's the case, you can always use `jQuery` instead of `$` to access any jQuery functionality such as `jQuery(selector)` or `jQuery.each()`, etc...

Comment: yes, thanks you are correct , but this issue pages are coming dynamical any idea to change ?

Comment: @Hunter, I have no idea what you're asking with this latest comment.  You need to explain your issue in more detail.  All jQuery code can be changed to use `jQuery` instead of `$` to avoid conflict with mootools or you can use the closure idea that Bobby Jack proposed in their answer for all jQuery code.

Answer (score 5):

Following on from jfriend00's answer, if you *do* find yourself having to use `jQuery` in the global scope to avoid conflicts, you can 'map' it to the dollar symbol and use it in local scope like so:

```
(function($) {
    // your familiar jQuery code using '$' can now go here
    // e.g.
    // $('#foo').hide();
})(jQuery);
```

I use this approach for my own jQuery code in Joomla. Joomla use mootools by default.